# Cannot find the file exeption

Tags: c#, visual-studio, cmd

When I try to run cade it throws "cannot find the file" exeption.

```
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo(@"for / f ""delims="" % i in ('""C:\Program Files (x86)\AnyDesk\AnyDesk.exe"" --get-id') do set CID =% i",
                 "echo % CID %"
                 );
            psi.UseShellExecute = false;
            psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            psi.CreateNoWindow = true;
            var proc = Process.Start(psi);
            string s = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
            Console.WriteLine(s);
```

Command line works in cmd.

```
for /f "delims=" %i in ('"C:\Program Files (x86)\AnyDesk\AnyDesk.exe" --get-id') do set CID=%i 
echo %CID%
```

Answer (score 0):

You have start process for command line using `cmd.exe` and have to pass your command then, like this

```
string command = @"for / f ""delims="" % i in ('""C:\Program Files (x86)\AnyDesk\AnyDesk.exe"" --get-id') do set CID =% i",
                 "echo % CID %"
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", command);
```

**Update:**

Try using escape character like this then,

```
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo("for /f \"delims =\" %i in ('\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\AnyDesk\\AnyDesk.exe\\\" --get-id') do set CID=%i && echo % CID % ");
```

Comment: My code works if I put other commands like `ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo("help"). ` I think I wrote slashes and quotes wrong in command wrong.

Comment: @r.Sayt - Try the update part I added to the answer